# Google App Engine - Connect to remote datastore locally using Objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have a google app engine app using the cloud datastore written in Java.  I have an entity class as follows:

```
@Entity 
public class Student {
    
    @Id private Long studentId;
    @Index private League league;
    @Index private String year;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    ...
}
```

I have a csv file of 1K students.  I need to upload this info into the cloud datastore.  I also generally want to interact locally with my remote datastore for testing etc.  I want to be able to do the following (row is a row of the csv file, i'll handle that).

```
for ( Row row : Iterator<Row> ){
   Student student = new Student(row);
   ofy().save().entity(student).now();
}
```

This code should run on my local machine and save entities to the cloud datastore.
I can connect to the datastore using the GCD JSON following the methodology at
https://github.com/JavaMonday/gcd-json-java

However, this doesn't allow for the use of objectify.  My app relies on objectify and need to populate in that manner.  Does anyone have a clue how to generically connect and populate the datastore that allows objectify/Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to connect to remote datastore from local machine, I think you need to use the Remote API: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi

> The Java SDK includes a library called Remote API that lets you
>   transparently access App Engine services from any Java application.
>   For example, you can use Remote API to access a production datastore
>   **from an app running on your local machine**.

This works for Datastore API, which are used by Objectify. So you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks @Deviling.  I tried this unsuccessfully as well.  I posted a followup question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27769581/gae-remote-api-cannot-connect