# Objectify with Play Framework 2

Tags: java, playframework, objectify, playframework-2.5

Is there a way to work with objectify when we don't use a servlet or a WEB-INF/web.xml?
I use Play! Framework 2.5.4 with Java and I don't know how to deal with that...

From this link : [Objectify wiki setup](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Setup)

I found a way to execute this code by creating a new module :

```
bind(ObjectifyFilter.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

But i don't know how to execute :

```
filter("/*").through(ObjectifyFilter.class);
```

Since I don't know how to do that, I tried that :

```
ObjectifyService.begin();
ofy().save().entity(registration).now();
```

But I only get the following exception :

> Error saving models.gcd.Registration@54cd7ad7: No API environment is registered for this thread.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like an interesting challenge.

Registering a filter in play framework is not very difficult although it does not follow servlet specification.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaHttpFilters

But the main problem I see is that (for the little I have read) this framework uses the Thread local context to store information about the transaction, and async tasks. And that is not compatible with the way play framework uses the treads following a non blocking model.
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ThreadPools

Not sure this information will help you, but will give you a bigger picture of the play framework.

Enjoy

Comment: Yes you are right (unfortunately). I found a workaround with this post, by using google remote API. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27762240/google-app-engine-connect-to-remote-datastore-locally-using-objectify In any case, thanks for your answer